# javax.mail version compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

which is the javax.mail version is compatible with java version 1.7.0_191
and which version of java is compatible with javax.mail-1.5.6.jar

please let us know the correct answer because i am facing a below exception, currently i have java 1.7.0-191 and javax.mail-1.5.6.jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIZE
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.fetch(IMAPFolder.java:1200)
    at com.idit.jafa.work_flow.server.manager.NewEmailManagerJAFA.extractMessages(NewEmailManagerJAFA.java:208)
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Stop using this very old (7 years) library. switch to a newer version

Comment: the [`pom`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.pom) suggest it is java 5 compatible. see the [docs on maven configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [`pom`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.pom) suggest it is Java 5 compatible.

```
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
        <compilerArgs>
        ...
```

You can learn how to read the `pom` file by referring to [maven configuration documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

As Jen suggested, you should use newer version (1.6.2) which support Java 7 and Java 9. However, please exercise caution as both version have known CVE as stated in the maven page. You should see if you could upgrade your code to be compatible with the latest fork called [`jakarta.mail`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail).